# JavaScript object is undefined until webpage is refreshed Microsoft Edge only

Tags: javascript, html, magento, onclick, microsoft-edge

I'm working with some code from a past employee. The phtml file in question has a button with an onclick event:

```
<button title="Submit" class="greenButton" id="submitBtn" onclick="loginOnepage.forgotpasswd()" type="button">Submit</button>
```

And it also has some JavaScript:

```
  var loginOnepage = new LoginOnePage(
      {
          formId: 'forgot-form-onepage',
          postUrl:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/forgotpassword', array('_secure' => true)); ?>',
          formNewCustomer: 'form-validate'

      }
  );
```

In a seperate js file, is the `LoginOnePage()` prototype:

```
var LoginOnePage = Class.create();
LoginOnePage.prototype = {  

    forgotpasswd: function(){
        /* code here */
    },

    ....
```

The onclick event is calling `forgotpasswd` method created in the `LoginOnePage` prototype. For some reason, when initially landing on the webpage where the button is located, there is no event that occurs when clicking the button. Checking the console gives this error:

`'LoginOnePage' is undefined`

When I refresh the page, everything works fine. No errors.

This is only happening in Microsoft Edge.

My suspicion right now is that the seperate js file containing the prototype is not loaded on the webpage the 1st time, but I don't understand why refreshing sets everything to right...

My company is also using Magento as an ecommerce platform.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Issue was the js file with the prototype code was set to load asynchronously in the xml file. – jakewies